# How do I write contents in build.gradle in Android.mk file?

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-instrumentation, android.mk

I already have a build.gradle file which I'm trying to integrate. I've a few statements which I'm not able to write to Android.mk file.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sec.android.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1'
}
```

I don't know how to write the following build configs from build.gradle to Android.mk

```
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1'
```

Can anybody help me with this? Also if I'm using those statements in Android.mk, do I need to include any libraries under /libs ?